# How to make the transform:translate-drag function of d3 more smooth?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

In [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachid/8d6ht3dL/) I have implemented elements in svg. I want the group of elements to be draggable and I have tried it with `d3.drag` and using `transform:translate`. The drag is not smooth. It flickers and jumps here and there.

What is the reason behind it and how can it be overcome?

The drag function is as follows:

```
var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
  .on("start", function() {})
  .on("drag", function(d, i) {
    var x = d3.event.x;
    var y = d3.event.y;
      d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
  })
  .on("end", function() {});
```

Comment: Gonna hazard a guess that the `d3.event.x` is relative to the parent, and by moving the parent and not the element you're dragging, you change the `d3.event.x` for the next 'tick'

Comment: Perhaps look into `drag.subject`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of attaching the drag listener to the foreign object div:

```
d3.select("#input-container-div").call(dragcontainer);
```

Add it to the svg group like this:

```
d3.select(d3.select("#input-container-div").node().parentNode.parentNode).call(dragcontainer);
```

Secondly instead of using d3.event.x/d3.event.y

```
var x = d3.event.x;
var y = d3.event.y;
```

Use dx and dy to get the mouse movement difference and store its for future drag.

Like this:

```
  this.x = this.x || 0;//reset if not there
  this.y = this.y || 0;

    this.x += d3.event.dx;
    this.y += d3.event.dy;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + this.x + "," + this.y + ")");
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/82gwvv9q/)

Comment: Yep it works. Maybe if I get rid of the divs and replace foreignObject with <g> it would be clean. Is using divs inside svg's good or bad?

Comment: if you use g instead of foreignObject then you cant use divs.. i think its better to not use divs and use SVG DOM elements instead unless you have some very good reason why you want to use it.